# Is it possible to use ARIMA model for multi-index time series dataframe? (using Python)

Tags: python-3.x, time-series, arima, timeserieschart

This is the original form of the data:

```
                          number       category                 location
        created_on          
2018-03-27 20:48:00 WEB34041280c          PFAST United States of America
2018-03-22 15:25:00 WEB34011829c     SHAREPOINT United States of America
2018-03-22 20:39:00 AMR34013866c     SHAREPOINT United States of America
2018-03-26 21:50:00 WEB34032848c GRAPHPAD PRISM United States of America
2018-04-01 13:27:00 AMR34063922c        EXPENSE United States of America
... ... ... ...
2018-08-12 12:11:00 MEX29239028i NETWORK PRINTER    Republic of Colombia
2018-08-17 12:15:00 MEX29266828i NETWORK PRINTER    Republic of Colombia
2018-08-30 14:08:00 MEX29331773i NETWORK PRINTER    Republic of Colombia
2018-09-05 13:53:00 MEX29358175i NETWORK PRINTER    Republic of Colombia
2018-09-11 21:44:00 MEX29388987i   LOCAL PRINTER      Argentine Republic
480616 rows × 3 columns
```

I've grouped it into 4-Hourly buckets to create a count of tickets based on category of tickets and the location for which they occur

```
grouped = df.groupby(['location', 'category', pd.Grouper(freq='4H')])['number'].count()
```

converting the Series object to dataframe:

```
grouped_df = grouped.to_frame()


                                                         number
              location    category           created_on 
Arab Republic of Egypt  AC ADAPTER  2018-04-03 12:00:00       1
                                    2018-04-29 08:00:00       2
                                    2018-05-27 08:00:00       2
                                    2018-05-30 08:00:00       2
                                    2018-06-10 08:00:00       1
... ... ... ...
United States of America    YAMMER  2018-07-25 16:00:00       1
                                    2018-07-31 12:00:00       1
                                    2018-08-03 16:00:00       1
                                    2018-09-11 20:00:00       1
                                    2018-09-21 12:00:00       1
245659 rows × 1 columns
```

In order to check for spike in ticket count (and predict /forecast the same) I have considered the counts being > zscore

```
import scipy
from scipy.stats import zscore
grouped_outl_df = grouped_df.loc[grouped_df.groupby('location')['number'].transform(zscore) > 1]


                                                             number
               location       category           created_on 
 Arab Republic of Egypt         ACCESS  2018-06-25 08:00:00       6
                               ACCOUNT  2018-04-24 12:00:00       3
                                        2018-05-31 12:00:00       3
                                        2018-06-27 08:00:00       3
                                        2018-06-28 08:00:00       4
... ... ... ...
United States of America    WINDOWS 10  2018-09-25 16:00:00      15
                                        2018-09-25 20:00:00       8 
                                        2018-09-26 12:00:00      11
                                        2018-09-26 16:00:00      11
                                        2018-09-27 16:00:00      11
19331 rows × 1 columns
```

1) My first issue begins now, I'm unable to plot the data using pivot techniques.

also when trying to use ARIMA model as shown below

```
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
def test_stationarity(timeseries):

    #perform dickey fuller test  
    print("Results of dickey fuller test")
    adft = adfuller(timeseries['number'],autolag='AIC')
    #output for dft will give us without defining what the values are.
    #hence we manually write what values does it explain using a for loop
    output = pd.Series(adft[0:4],index=['Test Statistics','p-value','No. of lags used','Number of 
                                         observations used'])
    for key,values in adft[4].items():
        output['critical value (%s)'%key] =  values
    print(output)

test_stationarity(grouped_outl_df)

Results of dickey fuller test
Test Statistics               -8.530215e+00
p-value                        1.042587e-13
No. of lags used               4.200000e+01
Number of observations used    1.928800e+04
critical value (1%)           -3.430689e+00
critical value (5%)           -2.861690e+00
critical value (10%)          -2.566850e+00
dtype: float64
```

From the p-value above its evident that our time series is Stationary

2) My 2nd issue begins when I'm unable to find the parameters of the ARIMA model (p, d, q) using the ACF and PACF plots

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import statsmodels.tsa.api as smt
import statsmodels.api as sm
from tqdm import tqdm_notebook
from itertools import product

def tsplot(y, lags=None, figsize=(12, 7), syle='bmh'):

    if not isinstance(y, pd.Series):
        y = pd.Series(y)

    with plt.style.context(style='bmh'):
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=figsize)
        layout = (2,2)
        ts_ax = plt.subplot2grid(layout, (0,0), colspan=2)
        acf_ax = plt.subplot2grid(layout, (1,0))
        pacf_ax = plt.subplot2grid(layout, (1,1))

        y.plot(ax=ts_ax)
        p_value = sm.tsa.stattools.adfuller(y)[1]
        ts_ax.set_title('Time Series Analysis Plots\n Dickey-Fuller: p={0:.5f}'.format(p_value))
        smt.graphics.plot_acf(y, lags=lags, ax=acf_ax)
        smt.graphics.plot_pacf(y, lags=lags, ax=pacf_ax)
        plt.tight_layout()

tsplot(grouped_outl_df.number, lags=10)
```

[image: ACF and PACF plots]

from the above plots I'm unable to decide what values I need to choose for ARIMA parameters p, d, q.

```
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
model = ARIMA(grouped_outl_df, order=(10,0,1))
result_AR = model.fit(disp = 0)
grouped_outl_df.number = grouped_outl_df.number.astype('float64')
result_AR.fittedvalues = result_AR.fittedvalues.astype('float64')
#plt.plot(grouped_outl_df)
#plt.plot(result_AR.fittedvalues, color='red')
#plt.title("sum of squares of residuals")
print('RSS : %f' %sum((result_AR.fittedvalues - grouped_outl_df["number"])**2))
```

I'm trying to use varies random values of p, d, q in order to minimize RSS value but I'm unable to do so and its time consuming and like a hit and trial method which I don't want to do

after minimizing the RSS value above I'm trying to forecast future datapoints, I need to forecast the ticket spike for the next 48 hours (2 days)

3) my third issue is that I'm not sure what values should I supply to the plot_predict and forecast functions in order to get a proper interpret-able plot to indicate the ticket count and the category and location where the next ticket spike will be.

```
result_AR.plot_predict(1,10)
x=result_AR.forecast(steps=10)
```

I get a plot something like this:

[image: plot_predict()]

whereas I want a plot something like this:

[image: desired plot_predict()]

the above plot is from another example though.

I will be very glad if someone can help me out with the issues that I'm facing.